# Sum of odd numbers using recursion

Tags: c, recursion

This might be simple but I'm new to recursion in c. I want to find the sum of odd integers based on user's input. For example if user inputs 3, function returns 9 (1 + 3 + 5 = 9)

```
 int recursiveSumNOdd(int n)
 {
  int start = -2; //later start = start+2, so it starts at 0
  int n1 = n*2; //total number of digits with rec
  int num = 0;
  int sum=0;
    int count=0;
 
    if(start>=n1) 
    {
     
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
     start = start+2;
     count++;
        sum = sum +recursiveSumNOdd(start);
    }
    return sum;
    }
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: Recursion is not a good approach to this. `int sumNOdd(int n) { return n*n; } ` seems to do the job.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting earlier, it's all good now

Comment: I guess from your code you believe that your variables' values are somehow transferred to the recursive calls, but they're not. Perhaps you need to learn about scoping of variables.

Comment: If really you are obliged to perform a recursion, use `sum(n) = sum(n-1) + 2*n - 1`

Comment: @PaulHankin: That is irrelevant because using recursion is a requirement of the assignment. Whether you think it is a good approach for finding the square of a number or for summing any series is irrelevant has no bearing on meeting the problem requirements. (A more relevant question would be whether summing a series is a productive exercise for **learning** to write recursive functions, even if it is not good production code, but it still has no bearing on the fact that the assignment does in fact require recursion.) If you have complaints, take them to the teacher; do not stress the student.

Comment: just saw your comment @PaulHankin and I agree, but I think he wants to understand better how recursion works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanations in comment:

```c
 int recursiveSumNOdd(int n) {
    if (n == 1 || n == 0)// first "if" in a recursive is its stop condition
        return n;
    return 2 * n - 1 + recursiveSumNOdd(n-1); // formula for 2->3, 3->5 etc
 }


int main(void) {
     printf("%d\n", recursiveSumNOdd(3));
    return 0;
}
```

NB: You may want to handle [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

NB2: You can have a mathematics formula to return instantly the result, it is way better, but I guess it was to understand better recursion?

```c
return n * n; // the sum of odd numbers is the square of user's input
```

Comment: its actually ```if (n == 1 || n == 0) return n;``` if you want to handle 0

Comment: no worries, its better to let him handle negative input and overflow, that's out of the scope of the explanation of what is a recursion

Comment: I would still use `n <= 1`, fewer CPU ops (1 vs 3), plus if something happens and number goes to negative it will go into endless loop or use `unsigned` in recursive

Comment: I agree, in general, but if you are looking for runtime then it would be better to just `return n < 0 ? -1 : n*n;` (fewer ops than the recursion :D) else you would return -42 for n = -42 which doesn't make much sense;

Answer (score 0):

You are over-complicating things.
You cannot have the sum of negative elements.

```
int sum_n_odd(unsigned n)
{
```

What is the sum of 0 (zero) elements?

```
    if (n == 0) return 0;
```

If you knew the sum of `n - 1` numbers, what is the sum of `n` numbers?

```
    return sum_n_odd(n - 1) + something; // something is easy to figure out
}
```